# Sql server table data syncing using Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am creating a small web site using the latest visual studio and Sql Server.  I will want to be able to "sync" my local database and my prod database. Any structure changes would be syncing from my local to prod. I will be using Entity framework 6 or 7 with code first migrations to handle that. I was wondering what is the best way to sync the data in the tables which I will want to sync both ways.

Comment: You can use VisualStudio tools. Tools > Sql Server > Schema Comparison. Then, Tools > Sql Server > Data Comparison. Of course, you have to do this manually

Comment: Thanks, that will work!

Comment: You are welcome. I'll post it as an answer, to help future people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VisualStudio tools.

Tools > Sql Server > Schema Comparison. Then, Tools > Sql Server > Data Comparison.

Of course, you have to do this manually.